# Creating multiple scope of functions inside a class in C++

Tags: c++, scope

I need static variables with same name visible to particular functions belonging to same class.

What I need is something like..

```
#include <XYZ.h>

{
  int A, B;
  void XYZ::f1(){}
  int XYZ::f2(){return 0;}
}

{
   int A, B;
   void XYZ::f3(){}
   float XYZ::f4(){return 0.0;}
}

{
   int A,B;
   void XYZ::f5(){}
   void XYZ::f6(){}
}
```

The variables A and B should be available within it's own scope and not anywhere else. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Because it is totally cryptic in this form...

Comment: What about making different classes with these as member functions?

Comment: The variables already are in their own scope, and unavailable anywhere outside of it. But you can't have function definitions there.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @T.C. More like an XYZ problem ;P

Comment: I need static variables with same name visible to particular functions.

Comment: Maybe you need to look into *namespaces*.

Comment: @cegprakash What you want is plain impossible in C++. Also it ["smells"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and probably violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Your question was probably downvoted and locked because of typical [XY-problem mistake](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I think I've asked the question clearly(after edits). If anyone can't understand please do post in comments. Vote to reopen plz..

Comment: @cegprakash your question is absolutely clear. And the answer is clear too: you can not do this in C++. What is unclear is what you want to achieve exactly. Knowing this, we could advise you some other appropriate way to solve your problem. There are several ways, but I am not supposed to guess which one will fit.

Comment: @Drop the clear answer is wrong. It's absolutely possible to do in C++. But it's more boiler plate than it's worth.

Comment: @Drop If you are clear about my question, why are you not clear about what I want? user2079303 is trying to help by suggesting some ways. That helps rather than putting this question on-hold.

Comment: @cegprakash We could suggest some other ways, like user2079303 did, but for this, we need to know **why** do you need this. For **what reason** you need to do what is impossible in C++? I just cannot enumerate all possible ways in answer. Add some usage code, describe what you want to call and how. Why you duplicating those variables, etc. Note that I neither downvoted, nor voted to put you question on hold.

Comment: I just need it as a part of my application. I didn't know that it's impossible in C++. I need it because I need it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be best to simply have different names for the variables. There's not much advantage in "hiding" them from other functions of the same class.

```
class XYZ {
    static int A1, B1, A2, B2; // come up with more descriptive names
}
```

Another good approach would be to split `XYZ` class into several smaller ones. It seems like it may have more than one responsibility, which is bad design.

If you really want this, here's how, but I think it's too elaborate:

```
class Scope1 { // one for each scope, come up with more descriptive names
    static int A, B;
    static void f1();
    static int f2();

    // use friend declarations to allow access only from specified functions
    // but if you don't care about that, make the functions public instead
    friend void XYZ::f1();
    friend int XYZ::f2();

    // you don't want instances of this class
    public: 
        Scope1() = delete;
}

// delegate
void XYZ::f1(){
    Scope1::f1();
}
int XYZ::f2(){
    return Scope1::f2();
}

// implementation
void Scope1::f1(){}
// ...
```

Comment: All the functions belong to the same class.

Comment: @cegprakash, in that case there's not much you can do really. Simply renaming the variables seems best option to me.

Comment: Actually, it *is* possible, but in my opinion it's too complicated for the little advantage that you get.

Comment: I really hate to do that (having variables with different names) as a part of a big software :|

Comment: @cegprakash, having different variable names is useful especially in big software, because it reduces ambiguity. Anyway, I've edited my answer to include the way you can do what you describe.